# Did Krishna ever suffer due to separation from beloved or due to unwanted circumstances?

Tags: krishna

We humans suffer a lot due to death and separation. Krishna fought many wars. Krishna had many relatives, friends and lovers.

My question is: Did Krishna ever suffer in any stage of his life?

Comment: if you're a gnani, the answer is no. if you're a bhakta, the answer is yes.

Comment: Is there any mention of his suffering in the Scriptures?

Answer (score 1):

Krishna suffered

1. When shyamantaka mani was lost the bad name fell on him.
2. When at the end of his life, Vali got his revenge (in next life) as Hunter.
3. In Ramavatar, he suffered due to separation from Sita. This was due to curse of Narada that he will suffer separation from wife and seeking the help of Vanaras i.e. Hanuman and other vanaras. This is because, as Lord Vishnu, he changed the face of Narada as Kapi and sent for a Swayamvara of Vishvamohini, who did penance to reach Vishnu in previous life and in Vishvamohini life, she joined Vishnu, at the Swayavamvara Mandap, where Narada appeared in Vanara face(done by Vishnu without his knowledge)

View Vishnupuran all volumes in Youtube. These are gathered there only.

Comment: Signatures generally aren't needed on Stack Exchange -- there's already a big thing just under your answer with your name and a link to your profile.

Comment: The OP asked only about Krishna Avatar. In the first example, there was no suffering. He proved his innocence. 2. The question is about Krishna Avatar only. Anyways, Vali got liberation and it was just a hunter who killed. It was not Vali. He accepted the curse of Gandhari. So it was not suffering 3, That was done to teach Narada that physical appearance is not important and no one can equal him. He changes Narada into a monkey. That's not about Krishna Avatar This is a story and that is not suffering by Krishna.So, correct your answer.